# rails 4 api rspec test http status code 410

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, http-status-code-410

I am trying to build the correct rspec test to verify my 410 status code handler is working. Here is what the route catch all looks like:

```
match '*not_found', to: 'error#error_404', via: :all
```

My simple error controller:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController

  def error_404
    head status: 410
  end

end
```

My current rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ErrorController do

  context "Method #error_404 handling missing routes =>" do
    it "Should have the 410 status code.." do
      get :error_404
      expect(response.status).to be(410)
    end
  end

end
```

Rspec Error Message:

```
  1) ErrorController Method #error_404 handling missing routes => Should have the 410 status code..
     Failure/Error: get :error_404
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"error_404", :controller=>"error"}
     # ./spec/controllers/error_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas on how to get this test to pass? I know the route will not exist but I am having trouble trying to use `get` to make it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if someone has a better idea here..... but, here is how I solved it:

First I installed [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

Then I adjusted the route to be more descriptive:

```
match '*not_found', to: 'error#error_status_410', via: :all
```

Then I adjusted my error controller:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController

  def error_status_410
    head status: 410
  end

end
```

Finally I adjusted my error controller spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ErrorController do

  context "Method #error_status_410 handling missing routes =>" do
    it "Should have the 410 status code.." do
      visit '/will-never-be-a-route'
      page.status_code == 410
    end
  end

end
```